# Magento Custom grid sort issue

Tags: magento-1.9, module, stock, inventory

Dear community I have made a custom module that will allow stock movement history to be kept for products.

However, as illustrated below: figure 1; pressing edit on an order in the admin order view, and submitting the new edited order. I am facing the issue of the records not being added in the correct order. Whereby, it looks to be adding the stock movement record for the newly created order first then the record for the restocking from the previous order.

[image: Fig.1]

Further complicating things is if you look at the top two records, it gets added in the correct order here.

I am struggling to identify why this could be and was wondering anyone could explain why?

**My config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vish_StockMovements>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </Vish_StockMovements>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <resources>
                <vish_stockmovements_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Vish_StockMovements</module>
                    </setup>
                </vish_stockmovements_setup>
            </resources>
            <blocks>
                <vish_stockmovements>
                    <class>Vish_StockMovements_Block</class>
                </vish_stockmovements>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <vish_stockmovements>
                    <class>Vish_StockMovements_Helper</class>
                </vish_stockmovements>
            </helpers>
            <models>
                <vish_stockmovements>
                    <class>Vish_StockMovements_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>vish_stockmovements_resource</resourceModel>
                </vish_stockmovements>
                <vish_stockmovements_resource>
                    <class>Vish_StockMovements_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <stock_movement>
                            <table>librex_stock_movement</table>
                        </stock_movement>
                    </entities>
                </vish_stockmovements_resource>
                <cataloginventory>
                    <rewrite>
                        <stock>Vish_StockMovements_Model_CatalogInventory_Stock</stock>
                    </rewrite>
                </cataloginventory>
            </models>
            <events>
                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>checkoutAllSubmitAfter</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>
                <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>saveStockItemAfter</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
                <cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale>
                    <observers>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>stockRevertProductsSale</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale>
                <catalog_product_import_finish_before>
                    <observers>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>catalogProductImportFinishBefore</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_import_finish_before>
                <controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
                    <observers>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>addStockMovementsTab</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
                <sales_order_item_cancel>
                    <observers>
                        <inventory><type>disabled</type></inventory>
                        <vish_stockmovements>
                            <class>vish_stockmovements/stock_observer</class>
                            <method>cancelOrderItem</method>
                        </vish_stockmovements>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_item_cancel>
            </events>
        </global>
        <adminhtml>
            <translate>
                <modules>
                    <Vish_StockMovements>
                        <files>
                            <default>Vish_StockMovements.csv</default>
                        </files>
                    </Vish_StockMovements>
                </modules>
            </translate>
        </adminhtml>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Vish_StockMovements before="Mage_Adminhtml">Vish_StockMovements_Adminhtml</Vish_StockMovements>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
    </config>
```

**My observer.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Vish
 * @package     Vish_StockMovements
 * @version     1.0.0
 */
class Vish_StockMovements_Model_Stock_Observer
{
    public function addStockMovementsTab()
    {


        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        /** @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs $block */
        $block = $layout->getBlock('product_tabs');
        $manageStock = $block->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getManageStock();
        if ($block && $block->getProduct() && $block->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'simple') {
            $block->addTab('stock_movements', array(
                'after' => 'inventory',
                'label' => Mage::helper('Vish_StockMovements')->__('Stock Movements'),
                'content' => $layout->createBlock('Vish_StockMovements/adminhtml_stock_movement_grid')->toHtml(),
            ));
        }
    }

    public function cancelOrderItem($observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

        $children = $item->getChildrenItems();
        $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered() - max($item->getQtyShipped(), $item->getQtyInvoiced()) - $item->getQtyCanceled();
        $manageStock = $item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getManageStock();
        if ($manageStock && $item->getId() && ($productId = $item->getProductId()) && empty($children) && $qty) {
            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->backItemQty($productId, $qty);
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($item->getProductId());
            $this->insertStockMovement($stockItem, sprintf(
                'Product restocked after order cancellation (order: %s)',
                $item->getOrder()->getIncrementId())
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function catalogProductImportFinishBefore($observer)
    {
        $productIds = array();
        $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
        $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('Vish_StockMovements/stock_movement');

        if ($adapter instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product) {
            $productIds = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds();
        } else {
            Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::getDataSourceModel()->getIterator()->rewind();
            $skus = array();
            while ($bunch = $adapter->getNextBunch()) {
                foreach ($bunch as $rowData) {
                    if (null !== $rowData['sku']) {
                        $skus[] = $rowData['sku'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!empty($skus)) {
                $productIds = $resource->getProductsIdBySku($skus);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($productIds)) {
            $stock = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock');
            $stocks = Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock')->getProductsStock($stock, $productIds);
            $stocksMovements = array();
            $datetime = Varien_Date::formatDate(time());
            foreach ($stocks as $stockData) {
                $manageStock = ($stockData['manage_stock'] == 1 ||  $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] == 1 ? true : false);
                if($manageStock === true){
                $stocksMovements[] = array(
                    'item_id'     => $stockData['item_id'],
                    'user'        => $this->_getUsername(),
                    'user_id'     => $this->_getUserId(),
                    'qty'         => $stockData['qty'],
                    'is_in_stock' => (int) $stockData['is_in_stock'],
                    'message'     => 'Product import',
                    'created_at'  => $datetime,
                );
                }
            }

            if (!empty($stocksMovements)) {
                $resource->insertStocksMovements($stocksMovements);
            }
        }
    }

    public function checkoutAllSubmitAfter($observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getEvent()->hasOrders()) {
            $orders = $observer->getEvent()->getOrders();
        } else {
            $orders = array($observer->getEvent()->getOrder());
        }
        $stockItems = array();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            if ($order) {
                foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
                    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem */
                    if ($orderItem->getQtyOrdered() && $orderItem->getProductType() == 'simple') {
                        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                            ->loadByProduct($orderItem->getProductId());
                        if($stockItem->getManageStock()){
                            if (!isset($stockItems[$stockItem->getId()])) {
                                $stockItems[$stockItem->getId()] = array(
                                    'item' => $stockItem,
                                    'orders' => array($order->getIncrementId()),
                                );
                            } else {
                                $stockItems[$stockItem->getId()]['orders'][] = $order->getIncrementId();
                            }
                       } 
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($stockItems)) {
            foreach ($stockItems as $data) {
                $this->insertStockMovement($data['item'], sprintf(
                    'Product ordered (order%s: %s)',
                    count($data['orders']) > 1 ? 's' : '',
                    implode(', ', $data['orders'])
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    public function insertStockMovement(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item $stockItem, $message = '')
    {
        if ($stockItem->getId()) {
            Mage::getModel('Vish_StockMovements/stock_movement')
                ->setItemId($stockItem->getId())
                ->setUser($this->_getUsername())
                ->setUserId($this->_getUserId())
                ->setIsAdmin((int) Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn())
                ->setQty($stockItem->getQty())
                ->setIsInStock((int) $stockItem->getIsInStock())
                ->setMessage($message)
                ->save();
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stockItem->getProductId())->cleanCache();
        }
    }

    public function saveStockItemAfter($observer)
    {

        if ($actionInstance = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_save') {    
               $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
            if (!$stockItem->getStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag() && $stockItem->getOriginalInventoryQty() != $stockItem->getQty()) {
                if (!$message = $stockItem->getSaveMovementMessage()) {
                        if (Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->getSessionId()) {
                            $message = 'Stock saved from Magento API';
                        } else {
                            $message = 'Stock saved manually';
                        }
                    }
                    $this->insertStockMovement($stockItem, $message);
                }           
        }
    }

    public function stockRevertProductsSale($observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $productId => $item) {
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
            if ($stockItem->getManageStock() && $stockItem->getId()) {
                $message = 'Product restocked';
                if ($creditMemo = Mage::registry('current_creditmemo')) {
                    $message = sprintf(
                        'Product restocked after credit memo creation (credit memo: %s)',
                        $creditMemo->getIncrementId()
                    );
                }
                $this->insertStockMovement($stockItem, $message);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getUserId()
    {
        $userId = null;
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $userId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $userId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
        }

        return $userId;
    }

    protected function _getUsername()
    {
        $username = '-';
        if (Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $username = Mage::getSingleton('api/session')->getUser()->getUsername();
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $username = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $username = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getUsername();
        }

        return $username;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Debugging I believe the dates are being included incorrectly. I need to keep the milliseconds also rather than the hours, minutes and seconds only.

The date field is calculated via the following:

```
 protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    if (!$object->getCreatedAt()) {
        $object->setCreatedAt($this->formatDate(time()));
    }

    return parent::_beforeSave($object);
}
```

This is stored in a datetime field in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the table they were added in the correct order. The grid was being sorted by the `create_at` field.

Whereby, when the records had the same created_at value it sorted it incorrectly.

The fix was to simply remove the following:

```
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
```

From my **_construct** method in grid.php.

I then amended the **_prepareCollection()** method:

```
 if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getVarNameSort())){
        $collection->getSelect()->order('movement_id DESC');   
 }
```

Adding a conditional order clause to the collection select, where it will set that sort if the user hasn't provided a sort.

Note:- The reason you cannot use **setDefaultSort** is because it uses the references in `->addColumn($this_ref, ...`
so if there's no corresponding `->addColumn` it'll do nothing.